# SQL Function Constraint for Denormalized Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

How do I create a function constraint for denormalized data?

```
-- graduation_class table
graduation_class_id | graduation_year_id
123                         1    
456                         2

-- user table
user_id |   graduation_class_id |   graduation_year_id
555             123                     1
556             123                     3  <--- bad data
557             456                     2
```

A graduation class can only be assigned to a sign graduation year.  The combination of the two is unique in the graduation_class table.

I want to create a function constraint on the graduation_year_id column on the user table to make sure the graduation_year_id is in sync with the proper id from the graduation_class table so that the record 556 in the user table will never happen.

** Please assume normalization is NOT a solution to this, or I wouldn't be asking this question! :) **

Comment: whether `graduation_class_id + graduation_year_id` is unique in `graduation_class` table

Comment: Yes, it's a unique combination in the graduation_class table.

Comment: What you want to achieve is best implemented through a FK constraint

Comment: I would populate `graduation_year_id` in the `user` table through a trigger.

Comment: Can you instead normalize the structures?

Comment: I already have a FK constraint, but that doesn't enforce that it's the right constraint, only that the id exists in any row in the graduation_class table.  It doesn't enforce which one.

Comment: I was talking about a composite FK. See answer below by @NoDisplayName. You can place a unique contraint in `graduation_class` table if you like (instead of a PK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by other answers, this schema is not ideal, but if you need to maintain data integrity in this schema before having the opportunity to clean things up, a function constraint will do this for you. First, we will create a function that takes in the `graduation_class_id` and `graduation_year_id` as parameters, and returns a bit value:

```
create function dbo.fn_check_graduation_year_id
    (
    @graduation_class_id int,
    @graduation_year_id int
    )
    returns bit
as
    begin
        declare @return bit = 1
        if @graduation_year_id != (select top 1 graduation_year_id
                                   from graduation_class
                                   where graduation_class_id = @graduation_class_id)
            set @return = 0
        return @return
    end
```

This function will return true if the `graduation_year_id` matches the value on the `graduation_class` table given the `graduation_class_id` value. Next, we will add the constraint to your `user` table, making sure the result of the check function returns true:

```
alter table [user] with nocheck add constraint ck_graduation_year_id
    check (dbo.fn_check_graduation_year_id(graduation_class_id,graduation_year_id) = 1)
```

Comment: have a look at here http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/12/17/be-careful-with-constraints-calling-udfs.aspx

Comment: In this case the function takes both values being checked, so an update to either that does not match the `graduation_class` table would return an error. Not an ideal solution, but an answer to the OP non the less.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of function create a `composite primary key` and a `foreign key` to fix your problem

Make the `graduation_class_id ,graduation_year_id` in `graduation_class` as composite `primary key`

```
ALTER TABLE graduation_class
ADD PRIMARY KEY (graduation_class_id ,graduation_year_id)
```

Now add `foreign key` in the user table

```
ALTER TABLE user
ADD FOREIGN KEY (graduation_class_id ,graduation_year_id)
REFERENCES graduation_class(graduation_class_id ,graduation_year_id)
```

This will ensure you to add only the row added to `user` table is already present in `graduation_class` table

Comment: I think `graduation_class_id` is intended to be the primary key of the `graduation_class` table, so the above might break referential integrity on that table.

Comment: @DavidFaber May be.. but that is the not that right column to act as primary key in that table should be altered

Comment: You don't need to alter `graduation_class` PK. A unique contraint on both columns (`graduation_class_id ,graduation_year_id`) would do.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - If you create a `unique constraint` then it cannot be referred in `user` table

Comment: This is what I have in mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225039/add-a-unique-constraint-of-a-sql-table-as-foreign-key-reference-to-an-another-sq

Comment: While this answer enforces referential integrity, I don't see how it prevents the incorrect value from being entered.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
alter table user
drop column graduation_year_id
```

If you need it, select it by joining to the graduation_year table

Comment: That's the ideal solution, but right now we need it denormalized... is there a good way to get this to work, assuming we need it denormalized?