# How to add unique constraint as foreign key ?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add unique constraint as foreign key by this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE SOME_TABLE ADD(
CONSTRAINT FK_ID FOREIGN KEY (S_ID) REFERENCES OTHER_TABLE(O_ID) UNIQUE (S_ID)
);
```

I thought that this statement is correct, but all time I got `"missing right parenthesis error"`. Probably I have wrong order of key words. 
Could you give me advice how to create an unique constraint ?

I red this issue:

[Add a unique constraint of a sql table as foreign key reference to an another sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225039/add-a-unique-constraint-of-a-sql-table-as-foreign-key-reference-to-an-another-sq)

but still I have problem with this.

Comment: The `unique (..)` part is invalid. The referenced table needs to have such a constraint, you can't specify that when creating the FK (you also don't need the parentheses around the whole `constraint ..` part)

Comment: Are you trying to require that S_ID be unique in table SOME_TABLE? You don't have to do that, and it is generally a sign of poor database design if you need to. O_ID must be unique in OTHER_TABLE, but the foreign key is almost never unique (in the table where it is foreign key, not in the "parent" table where it is primary key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need parentheses.  Second, this is two constraints and you might as well give both names:

```
ALTER TABLE SOME_TABLE
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ID FOREIGN KEY (S_ID) REFERENCES OTHER_TABLE(O_ID);

ALTER TABLE SOME_TABLE
    ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_ST_S_ID UNIQUE (S_ID);
```

Comment: So I have to have two different constraints, Am  I understand you correctly  ?

Comment: Yes, your conditions correspond to two constraints.